# Is there anything wrong with my glsl shader loading code?

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, glsl, shader

The problem is that, shaders (pretty simple ones, as I'm learning OpenGL) fail to compile in a seemingly random manner (and gives random error messages * ). 
The same shaders, however, compile after about 3 or 4 tries.
Here is the code:

```
Shader::Shader(GLenum Type,std::string filename)
{
    shader_type = Type;

    std::ifstream ifs(filename);
    if(!ifs)
        throw(std::runtime_error("File:"+filename+" not opened."));
    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream<<ifs.rdbuf();

    const GLchar* data = stream.str().c_str();

    handle = glCreateShader(shader_type);
    glShaderSource(handle,1,static_cast<const GLchar**>(&data),0);

    glCompileShader(handle);

    int status;
    glGetShaderiv(handle,GL_COMPILE_STATUS,&status);
    if(status == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int loglength;
        glGetShaderiv(handle,GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH,&loglength);

        auto data = new char[loglength];

        glGetShaderInfoLog(handle,loglength,&loglength,data);

        std::string strdata(data);
        delete [] data;

        throw(std::runtime_error(strdata));
    }
}
```

Note that the shaders aren't missing newlines at the end, has an extra space after the last semicolon and uses tabs instead of spaces.   (as suggested in *various* old posts over the internet!).

- Here are two error messages produced from the same vertex shader here, not at the same time:

```
#version 330
in vec2 Position;
uniform mat4 transform;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = transform*vec4(Position,0.0f,1.0f);

}
```

Errors:

```
0(1) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected $undefined at token "<undefined>"


0(6) : error C0000: syntax error, unexpected '!', expecting ',' or ')' at token "!"
```

And sometimes it just works !
Is it a problem with my drivers ? 
(I'm using the recent 302.x stable nvidia binary drivers on Arch Linux 64 bit, with an aged 9600 GSO card )

P.S: The code works as expected ,whenever the shader compiles correctly, so I think it shoud be correct. 
I'll be happy to post a working(sometimes !) example as a zip file if the problem can't be found from this, and someone wants to take a look.

Comment: Most likely the shader compiler is seeing garbage characters. Make sure that the input is what you expect it to be.

Comment: Input ? as in the text file in which the shader is stored ?

Comment: No, the actual data you pass into glShaderSource. Perhaps because of the stream getting destroyed after `const GLchar* data = stream.str().c_str();` the data you pass into it is garbage.

Comment: @Bart is right, you will need to log the shader source at the point of submission to glShaderSource(...) and the error message generated(if any).

Comment: However I do it, the middleman (a string, a stream or whatever) is going to have the same problem, I think. What would you suggest ?

Comment: @ananthonline: Let me try that..

Comment: err.. how exactly do I do that ? I can't find anything in glGetShaderiv's parameter options that will let me do that.

Comment: Start a debugger. Look at the content of `data` when calling `glShaderSource`. Big chance that is garbage.

Comment: Yes, it was.
I've replaced the stringstream with a loop running std::getline and appending to a std::string. It seems inefficient compared to dumping the whole buffer at once, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
const GLchar* data = stream.str().c_str();
```

This is bad. If you want the string's data, you need to *store it*. `str` will return a *copy* of the buffer, which you then get a pointer to with `c_str`. Once that temporary is destroyed (at the end of this line), that pointer will point to memory you no longer have access to.

The correct code is this:

```
std::string dataString = stream.str();
const GLchar *data = reinterpret_cast<GLchar*>(dataString.c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks,that seems to do it. Can you suggest a way to prevent the data being copied around so many times (File-> istream -> ostringstream -> string -> char* -> wherever OpenGL takes it ).
I'm thinking of something like memory mapping the file, but am not sure if it'll work.

Comment: @manasij7479: Half of those aren't copying. File->istream is going to happen, whether you use streams, memory-mapped files, etc. It's called *loading the file.* The copy into the string-stream is not strictly necessary; you could construct the `std::string` from a pair of istream iterators. So you don't really need the `stringstream`. The conversion to a `char*` likely doesn't copy anything. And OpenGL is going to take its copy one way or another.

Comment: Thought so, so asked before attempting premature optimization.
Is there a way to get an address to the char array directly from the buffer (filebuf, iirc) of the ifstream ? That could do away with constructing the string.

Comment: @manasij7479: The `ifstream` doesn't actually *have* the characters yet. Like I said, reading from the stream is called "loading the file into memory." You must load the file into memory before you can read from it.

Comment: I tried your code @manasij7479 but `reinterpret_cast` cannot  convert `const *char` into `GLchar*`